# NSMutableURLRequest cachePolicy not working

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest

Here's my code

```
    let url = NSURL(string: user_url)
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest.init(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
```

I'm getting this error:

`Type 'NSURLRequestCachePolicy' has no member 'reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData'`

I pulled this [constant from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy/1407674-reloadignoringlocalcachedata) so I am wondering where I am going wrong here?

This is for Swift 2.3 (not much choice/decision) + XCode 8.

Comment: What versions of Xcode and Swift are you targeting?

Comment: @JimMatthews added details to question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Swift 2.x you want:

```
let url = NSURL(string: user_url)
var request = NSMutableURLRequest.init(URL: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
```

`ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` was renamed to `reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` as part of the great Swift 3 renaming, hence the documentation. To find out what the compiler is looking for, command-click on the method call, and then on the parameter type (`NSURLRequestCachePolicy`) -- that will take you to the declaration that the compiler is actually using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Edited (Swift 2)**

```
NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 4)
```

Comment: I am seeing Use of unresolved identifier 'MutableURLRequest' when I try this.

Comment: You must be using Swift2. If so, use capital character. Like ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData.